# Changing an old Price Pfister pull-out Acrylic shower knob to an easier handle

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have an old Price Pfister single-handle acrylic shower knob that pulls out to turn on and then twists for temperature change. Is there an adapter that can be used to allow a metal handle to lever-on then twist for temperature with the existing cartridge? Or will I need a whole new cartridge to get away from the acrylic knob?

Comment: IDK if there are after-market knobs but those "yank straight out of the wall" shower valves are an embarrassment to the human race.  Get out the sledge hammer!

Comment: Break out your wallet. In my experience, Price Pfister parts are made of unobtanium. You'll have to go to a plumbing supply place, and they may not sell it to you if you're not a contractor. I keep finding the coolest PP faucets, then have to debate whether I want to buy the cool one, or one that can be repaired down the road...

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certain that you will need to change the whole shower mixing valve to get the type of control that you desire. There is next to no standardization between manufacturers and different models of these products.

Changing a shower valve generally requires access to the inside of the wall area where the plumbing and the valve are located. This means that replacement is no trivial task. The best situation is often when the valve is mounted within an interior wall and you can gain access to the wall cavity from the opposite side of the wall by opening up the drywall.

Answer (score 0):

There are conversion kits for practically every brand of shower valve. Try your local big box home store, and Amazon. You may have to go to a plumbing supply store, but they are out there.  I cannot guide you to an exact source without more info on your valve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can get a PP shower set with the metal handle.  The kit comes with an extension rod.  The rod screws into the center of the cartridge where the screw from the old handle would have gone.  Then the metal handle set screw attaches to the extension.

The kit (which also included a round escutcheon, shower head and shower nipple), was LJ89-020C.

That said, it is very difficult to grasp the control except by the handle, which is offset from the center.  Unless your cartridge just glides in and out for flow control, it's going to put a torque on the cartridge as you turn the water on.  If that happens, it will probably reduce the life of some part in there.